# Options of the ‘ps’ utility

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

Can someone please enlighten on what the difference is when passing the 'j' and '-l -y' options to the 'ps' utility.

An other good 'ps' resource is welcome too.

Comment: I think this post answers my question better, sorry for ambiguity. http://serverfault.com/questions/95171/options-of-the-ps-utility

Comment: I understand you asked this quite some time ago, but just for future reference, please do not cross-post questions on multiple Stack Exchange sites. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The ultimate resource would be the [ps man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ps). You can access this from your terminal as well by typing `man ps`.

As for the options:

```
-j     jobs format
-l      long format
-y      Do not show flags; show rss in place of addr. This option can
        only be used with -l.
```

output of each switch (other combinations are possible):

```
[john@awesome]$ps -j
PID  PGID   SID TTY          TIME CMD
30693 30693 30693 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
30879 30879 30693 pts/1    00:00:00 ps

[john@awesome]$ps -l
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 S  1089 30693 30691  0  78   3 -  1166 wait   pts/1    00:00:00 bash
0 R  1089 30882 30693  0  80   3 -  1052 -      pts/1    00:00:00 ps

[john@awesome]$ps -ly
S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI   RSS    SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
S  1089 30693 30691  0  78   3  1488  1166 wait   pts/1    00:00:00 bash
R  1089 30890 30693  0  80   3   820  1052 -      pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```